# Custom Field: Display only if a specific key is selected outside the loop

Tags: custom-field, post-meta, meta-value

I might be doing this all wrong. I have a custom field called "enable_adsense" and the value can be either "yes" or "no"

What I'm trying to do is display something if the value is "yes" and something else if it's "no".

Here's what I have so far:

```
    <?php
global $post;
$enable_adsense = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'enable_adsense', true);
var_dump($enable_adsense);
if ($enable_adsense == 'yes') { ?>

    Adsense code goes here

<?php } else { ?>
```

Comment: If your meta value is what you say it is that should work. What is the question?

Comment: That's the thing it's not working.

Comment: Then your post meta is not what you say it is. Do some debugging-- say, `var_dump($disable_adsense);`

Comment: This is how it appears: [Screeenshot](http://www.ihiphopmusic.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/custom-field.png), does this have to be in the loop? Because it's in the sidebar and only returning what comes after the "else"

Comment: For `$post` to work correctly, yes, it has to be in a Loop. I didn't ask for a screenshot of the backend. I asked for a `var_dump`.

Comment: I'm a beginner a PHP, I don't know what to do with var_dump($disable_adsense); I showed the screenshot so you could see it was correct. My particular situation is outside the loop.

Comment: Put the `var_dump` code right before the `if` statement and post the output.

Comment: @s_ha_dum OK so I thought the solution I had worked but it doesn't it just keeps defaulting the else results. I added the 'var_dump' like you said along with 'global $post;' since I'm using it outside the loop. This is what it's returning 'string(0)""'. I updated the code above.